# Insert 8 empty (NA) columns every fourth column in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, insert, na

I have a dataframe which is called DFSpecies. It has 999 Rows and 80 columns. I need to add 8 empty columns every fourth column.

The result should thus be 4 columns with data from DF_Species followed by 8 NA columns and so on...

How can i do this?

Thanks you!

Comment: Hopefully you did not try my solution before my last edit, I've confirmed it works for your needs exactly as described. That is with exactly 80 columns.Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This Should do the trick in Base-R, someone else may have a "cleaner" solution from a package.

```
DFSpecies <- cbind(DFSpecies[1:4],NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,DFSpecies[5:80])

for(i in 1:19){
  DFSpecies <- cbind(DFSpecies[1:((i*12)+4)],NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,DFSpecies[(i*12+1):NCOL(DFSpecies)])
  }

DFSpecies <- cbind(DFSpecies,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
```

Comment: You can add a little bit of flexibility to the number of columns and remove the first line by replacing the for-loop with the following:
`for(i in 1:(ceiling(ncol(DFSpecies)/4)-1)){
  DFSpecies <- cbind(DFSpecies[1:((i*12)-8)], NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA, DFSpecies[((i*12)-7):ncol(DFSpecies)])
}
`  (This code looks gross in a comment, but I didn't feel like it was different enough to justify it's own answer.)

Answer (score 0):

Base R Solution:

```
# Number of cols per 8 na_cols: n_cols => numeric vector: 
n_cols <- 4

# Number of NA vectors per n_cols: na_n_cols => numeric vector: 
na_n_cols <- 8 

# Allocate some memeory to store the split data.frame: df_list => list
df_list <- vector("list", ncol(df) / n_cols)

# Split the data.frame into ncol(df)/n data.frames in the list: df_list => list
df_list <- split.default(df, rep(1:length(df_list), each = n_cols))

# Flatten the list back into a single data.frame appending 8 NA vectors for
# every 4 original vectors: na_appended_df => data.frame
na_appended_df <-
  do.call("cbind", lapply(seq_along(df_list), function(i) {
    tmp <- data.frame(x1 <- rep(NA, nrow(df)))
    x <- cbind(df_list[[i]],
               setNames(data.frame(tmp[rep(1, each = na_n_cols)]), paste0("na_", ((
                 ((na_n_cols * i) + i - 1):(((n_na_cols * i) + i + na_n_cols + n_cols))
               )))[1:na_n_cols]))
    return(x)
  }))
```

Data:

```
tmp <- data.frame(x1 <- rnorm(999, mean = 3.5, sd = 2))
df <-
  setNames(data.frame(tmp[rep(1, each = 80)]), paste0("x_", 1:80))
```

Comment: @Pepijn Devriendt please upvote and accept the answer provided if you find it solves your problem.